# `fstab` entry for bootable system on SSD moving between machines

Tags: fstab

I have a (perhaps) unusual setup: a bootable system on a SSD which I carry between two essentially identical  (AMD) machines. This gives me at each site EXACTLY the same Debian environment (for all tool setup, preferences etc. etc.).  This works well, except:

- the two machines each have a HD and I want to use a swap file locally. What is the best `fstab` entry to avoid long waits either when starting or shut down?
- how can I mount an additional local partition which contains files rarely changing and which can be synced (e.g. with syncthing). An entry in the `fstab` to mount `additionalSpace` in the `home directory` is not practical: when the local disk is not present the directory is filled using space of the SSD.

Anybody encountered a similar setup? Any suggestions how this could be achieved?

Comment: While I have full installs on both a Z97 and z170, I also have a full install on my SSD (and multiple flash drives). With external drive I have to partition in advance to have ESP on it & tell installer not to use swap partitions on internal drives. New installs now use swap file if swap partition not found. If you have 4GB of RAM or more you should not be using swap unless maybe editing large photos or videos. I rsync data from HDD to SSD. I like labels on every partition for mounting. You may want noauto and nofail options in fstab if using fstab.

Answer (score 0):

> the two machines each have a HD and I want to use a swap file locally. What is the best fstab entry to avoid long waits either when starting or shut down?

Apply the same disk label on both the local disks and reference the device using the that in the fstab, e.g.

```
host1 # mkswap -L commonswap /dev/sdb6

host2 # mkswap -L commonswap /dev/sdb2

echo "LABEL=commonswap swap sw 0 0" >>/etc/fstab
```

I suspect your second question (should be one question per post) is answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/570255/prevent-the-possiblity-of-writing-data-to-an-unmounted-mount-point-directory).